# could someone tell me why this code is not working as expected?

Tags: python, nltk

```
def ethos(file):
    """Open a local file, convert its content into tokens.Match tokens with list provided, return matching list."""
    f = open(file)
    raw = f.read()
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
    list = [ 'perfect' ,'companion' , 'good' , 'brilliant', 'good']
    for tokens in list:
        return tokens
```

I wrote this code with the idea that it should return all the tokens in the text which matches the list defined, but it is returning only one token and that too the one in the beginning of the list
I also tried to add and empty list and append the matching words but it doesn't seems to work, so kindly let me know if any body has any ideas, please reply soon

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here, but the main point is that a function will only execute the first `return` it comes across. So you loop through each item in the list, and `return` the first one--at which point the function stops executing, because it returned.

I think what you *want* is to check each word in the text to see whether it's in your list, and then return all the matching words. To do that, you need to actually perform a comparison somewhere, which you're not doing at the moment. You might rewrite your loop to look something like this:

```
# Don't use "list" as a variable name! Also, there's no need for two "good" entries.
words_to_match = ['perfect' ,'companion' , 'good' , 'brilliant']

matching_tokens = []
for token in tokens:
    if token in words_to_match:
        matching_tokens.append(token) # add the matching token to a list
return matching_tokens # finally, return all the tokens that matched
```

---

Once you understand what it is that you're doing with the explicit loop above, note that you can rewrite the whole thing as a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
words_to_match = {'perfect' ,'companion' , 'good' , 'brilliant'} # using a set instead of a list will make the matching faster
return [t for t in tokens if t in words_to_match]
```

Comment: one more thing, I saw the tokens of my text they are not in the form of words rather they are segmented as sentences, so i feel my code now is not returning any results. any suggestions?

Comment: @gargijha I'm not very familiar with NLTK, but from a glance it looks like what you've written should work. If you continue to have issues with getting the `word_tokenize` function working properly, I suggest opening a new question on that topic, showing sample input and output, to draw the attention of people experienced in NLTK.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to do

```
return [i for i in tokens if i in list]
```

The way you wrote it, it will iterate through each word in `list`. But the first thing it does in the loop is `return`. So all it will do is return the word `'perfect'` every time regardless of what comes back in `tokens`. So the modified code (assuming everything else functions correctly) would be

```
def ethos(file):
"""Open a local file, convert its content into tokens.Match tokens with list
    provided, return matching list."""
    f = open(file)
    raw = f.read()
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
    list = [ 'perfect' ,'companion' , 'good' , 'brilliant', 'good']
    return [i for i in tokens if i in list]
```

Also, some miscellaneous tips:

> 1. Don't name that variable `list` because you are name shadowing
> 2. Your variable `list` could be a `set` then you could have O(1) lookup times instead of O(N)